# Does ForEach-Object swallow terminating errors under certain circumstances?

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.0

I'm seeing some odd behavior under a very specific scenario when using ForEach-Object to invoke a script that throws a terminating error.

It's as if under certain circumstances, terminating errors within the `-Process` script block do not cause the overall script execution to halt as I'd expect...execution continues anyway.

It's making me wonder if there are any gotchas when using `ForEach-Object` (or any cmdlet/advanced function for that matter) under these circumstances.

---

## Examples

The following example represents what I'd expect:

```
$childScriptPath = '.\childscript.ps1'
Set-Content $childScriptPath -Value @'
    $ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'

    # normally non-terminating, but should be terminating here due
    # to $ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'
    Get-Command command_that_does_not_exist 

    # We never get here as expected
    Write-Host 'After Get-Command: should not get here'
'@

"something doesn't matter what" | ForEach-Object {
    & $childScriptPath
}

# Shouldn't get here due to terminating error...works as expected.
Write-Host 'Script should have thrown a terminating error; should not get here'
```

The following example does NOT work as I'd expect. Note that the only difference is the fact that it's using `Set-StrictMode` followed by a reference to an undefined variable to cause the error instead of calling `Get-Command` with a command that does not exist:

```
$childScriptPath = '.\childscript.ps1'
Set-Content $childScriptPath -Value @'
    $ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'
    Set-StrictMode -Version latest

    # normally would silently continue, but should throw a
    # terminating error here due to $ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'
    # and Set-StrictMode -Version latest
    $undefinedVariable

    # We never get here as expected
    Write-Host 'After undefined variable: should not get here'
'@

"something doesn't matter what" | ForEach-Object {
    & $childScriptPath
}

# Shouldn't get here, but it does!!!
Write-Host 'Script should have thrown a terminating error; should not get here'
```

If anyone has any insight, it'd be greatly appreciated.

---

## Additional Info

In reality, this seems to be a behavior difference between cmdlets/advanced functions over regular functions because if we take the "does not work as expected" example above and use a hand-rolled `ForEach-Object` function implemented as a regular non-advanced function, it works as expected:

```
$childScriptPath = '.\childscript.ps1'
Set-Content $childScriptPath -Value @'
    $ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'
    Set-StrictMode -Version latest

    # normally would silently continue, but should throw
    # terminating error here due to $ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'
    # and Set-StrictMode -Version latest
    $undefinedVariable

    # We never get here as expected
    Write-Host 'After undefined variable: should not get here'
'@

function ForEach-Object2 {
    param (
        [scriptblock]$ScriptBlock
    )

    process {
        & $ScriptBlock
    }
}

"something doesn't matter what" | ForEach-Object2 {
    & $childScriptPath
}

# Shouldn't get here...works as expected.
Write-Host 'Script should have thrown a terminating error; should not get here'
```

On the other hand, if we convert the hand-rolled `ForEach-Object` function into an advanced function, we're back to the unexpected behavior:

```
$childScriptPath = '.\childscript.ps1'
Set-Content $childScriptPath -Value @'
    $ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'
    Set-StrictMode -Version latest

    # normally would silently continue, but should throw
    # terminating error here due to $ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'
    # and Set-StrictMode -Version latest
    $undefinedVariable

    # We never get here as expected
    Write-Host 'After undefined variable: should not get here'
'@

function ForEach-Object2 {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param (
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline=$true)]        
        [object]$InputObject,

        [Parameter(Position=0)]
        [scriptblock]$ScriptBlock
    )

    process {
        & $ScriptBlock $InputObject
    }
}

"something doesn't matter what" | ForEach-Object2 {
    & $childScriptPath
}

# Shouldn't get here, but it does!!!
Write-Host 'Script should have thrown a terminating error; should not get here'
```

Comment: PowerShell is open-source now, I think the ForEach-Object code in C# is here: [Cmdlet("ForEach", "Object"](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/7a89b33f8b0de97f592f65354ea435df7f163302/src/System.Management.Automation/engine/InternalCommands.cs#L27) with the relevant `void ProcessRecord()` block at line 251, if you really want to dig into it...

Comment: Yeah...believe it or not, I started down that path...leading me here before I got lost: https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/src/System.Management.Automation/engine/lang/scriptblock.cs#L948